# NoSQL database for Windows with Offline sync capability

Tags: windows, database, offline, synchronization, nosql

I develop a Windows 7+ desktop application that currently uses Microsoft SQL Server to hold the data and a local DB to work offline.

Now I want to switch to a NoSQL database. That DB should work on Windows too and have offline and auto-sync capabilities on-board.

I could run a dedicated server to hold the data as I currently run a server with Microsoft SQL Server on it since I don't want to pay for storing my data online in the cloud.

<sub>PS: *Google Firebase* comes close but is cloud storage.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

[Couchbase Mobile (i.e. Couchbase Lite + Sync Gateway)](https://www.couchbase.com/products/mobile) might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

[CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) shold work. As far as I can tell it completes all your requirements: works on desktop, has offline capabilities, and functions similarly to MongoDB.

Comment: CouchDB local does not have auto sync option read this article https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/local.html

Comment: @mlhazan Ah, missed that requirement sorry. Should I delete my answer?